# wxpython: breaking from a while loop when an event occurs

Tags: wxpython

I want to create a wxpython application which buffers audio input inside an infinite while loop, until a chekbox is clicked. I tried out the following code, but it didn't responds to any event and simply iterates in the while loop. Please help me to continue my project work. Thanks in advance

```
    while 1:
      #buffering of audio data
      if self.checkbox_1.GetValue(): #checking for an external event but this external event  is not working and i cant even check the check box
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is threads. By creating an infinite loop, you are blocking your UI's event loop. So do the buffering piece in a separate thread. In the thread, you will need to do the buffering in chunks (like a kilobyte at a time). After each chunk, use one of wxPython's threadsafe methods to ask wxPython if the checkbox is checked. The thread-safe methods are wx.CallAfter, wx.CallLater and wx.PostEvent. I would recommend the first or the last.

The wxPython wiki explains how to add threads:

- http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks

I also have an old article on the topic:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/22/wxpython-and-threads/